# How to use backbone parse nested json?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, backbone.js, underscore.js

I tried a few solutions related to similar questions but still no luck. The json structure is not very complicated except nested (below).

```
{ "name" : "John Smith",
  "gender" : "male",
  "address" : { "city" : "New York",
                "state" : "NY"
              }
}
```

My goal is in the erb file to access "city" and "state" like below.

```
<script id="person-template" type="text/template">
  <div class="person">
    <span class="name"><%%= get('name') %></span>
    <span class="gender"><%%= get('gender') %></span>
    <span class="city"><%%= get('city') %></span>  
    <span class="state"><%%= get('state') %></span>
  </div>
</script>
```

Right now I get stuck on get('city') and get('state'), don't know how to deal with it. Thanks a lot for the hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your model definition you want to override the parse method to return the data as you want it.

```
var YourModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  parse: function(data){
    return {
      name: data.name,
      gender: data.gender,
      city: data.address.city,
      state: data.address.state
    };
  }
});
```

If you are setting the model value explicitly from json then you have a slightly different problem. You can retrieve the address portion of the model and access it's properties directly:

```
person.get('address').city // this should contain the city value
```

**WARNING:**

if you do this then the `address` object you retrieve will be mutable, so:

person.get('address').city = "Denver"

will change the address property without trigger any change events. For this reason it is generally better to either:

- have flat model structures (the parse method above is an example of that)
- copy object values for modification or return (using _.clone or something)

Comment: I try get('city') as you suggested, but it does not work. But if I do get('address'), it shows '[object Object]'. Is there any way I can further retrieve city from address?

Comment: You should not end up with a model that has an address property. Perhaps if you post more of your code I can better help.